# Getting Invalid Client Error - When trying to connect to eclinical works FHIR Sandbox

Tags: hl7-fhir

Can someone share the correct steps if they were successfully able to connect

Followed the documentation given on the EHR website but it did not work out

Comment: You need to provide more details in order to be effectively helped here. What is the exact error message and status code you are getting? Which API call is returning the error? Which kind of app launch/authentication scheme are you following? What have you tried already?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.